# Emacs org-mode totals table

Tags: org-mode

I have an org file, describing a project:

```
* task1
** task1-1
     :PROPERTIES:
     :price: 10
     :given: <2012-11-08 Thu>
     :END:
** task1-2
     :PROPERTIES:
     :price: 11
     :given: <2012-11-08 Thu>
     :END:


* task2
** task2-1
     :PROPERTIES:
     :price: 20
     :given: <2012-11-08 Thu>
     :END:
** task2-2
     :PROPERTIES:
     :price: 21
     :given: <2012-11-08 Thu>
     :END:
```

I used org-collector to produce a totals table:

```
#+BEGIN: propview :id global :conds ((not (= price 0))) :cols (ITEM price)
| ITEM      | price |
|-----------+-------|
| "task1-1" |    10 |
| "task1-2" |    11 |
| "task2-1" |    20 |
| "task2-2" |    21 |
|-----------+-------|
|           |    62 |
#+TBLFM: @6$2=vsum(@2$2..@5$2)
#+END:
```

But I want to have something like this:

```
| ITEM      | price |
|-----------+-------|
| "task1-1" |    10 |
| "task1-2" |    11 |
| "task2-1" |    20 |
| "task2-2" |    21 |
|-----------+-------|
| Total     |    62 |
```

How to do it?

Comment: Could you precise what you are able to obtain, and what's missing, especilly, why isn't `tast2` taken into account ? If that's your question, please state it and provide detail on `:id global` (what it should do, what it doesn't)

Comment: task2 is taken now, I used an outdated org-collector file. Now it takes it. But I still can't produce totals together with propview. I updated the table.

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of the `TBLFM` line, or to make the word *Total* appear ? I don't see many more differences between what you seem to have, and what you want to obtain.

Comment: "Are you trying to get rid of the TBLFM line, or to make the word Total appear ?" Yes. I have to embed this stuff into elisp function.

Comment: The answer below is telling you how to make your own total. If you're trying to do it with `org-collector`... I think you'll just have to add the "Total" line yourself or edit the code. I don't think for something like this someone's going to edit code for you. Others might want "Sum" or "total" or "\*Total\*" to make it bold or "/Total/" for italics... it's doing the hard part, which seems to be, well, the hard part.

Comment: "I don't think for something like this someone's going to edit code for you." I know. I'll try to write the code myself and post it here. It may be useful.

Answer (score 6):

For the “Total” line, you can add a line `|Total| |`, press <kbd>C-u C-c =</kbd> in the empty cell (to define a formula for it), and enter the formula `vsum(@1$2..@4$2)`. (If you wanna recalc, that's <kbd>C-u C-c C-c</kbd> for all.)

I don't know about org-collector, so can't help you with this part. Run it on the entire document (is `:id global` working?), or shift everything by one level to the right for it to be inside a single tree, maybe.

Comment: For a quick total, you can also use the `C-c +` command, `org-table-sum`. The answer given here is better though since you can recalculate the formula rather than just have a value if the values change.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this one out this morning.  The answer you're looking for with Org-Collector is straightforward.  Just put the table formulae two blank lines beneath the beginning of the property view and it'll be calculated automatically when the property view is evaluated (with `C-c C-c`).

```
#+BEGIN: propview :scope tree :cols (ITEM CLOCKSUM EFFORT) :match "TODO=\"TODO\"" :noquote ALL


#+TBLFM: @>$1=Totals::@>$2=vsum(@I..@II);t::@>$3=vsum(@I..@II);t
#+END:
```

If you want to turn this into a generic yasnippet, you need to escape the $ and the \:

```
#+BEGIN: propview :scope tree :cols (ITEM CLOCKSUM EFFORT) :match "TODO=\\"TODO\\"" :noquote ALL


#+TBLFM: @>\$1=Totals::@>\$2=vsum(@I..@II);t::@>\$3=vsum(@I..@II);t
#+END:
```

Now, you can add a generic property view that calculates the time so far and effort remaining for each step of a project, as well as the total time overall.